# MyEclipse Could not open the editor: Invalid thread state detected on read

Tags: myeclipse

I'm using MyEclipse developing a web project. Today when I open a jsp file in it, I got a pop-up box which says "The Linux WYSIWYG design panel is still under development. To access an experimental version of this design panel restart with the commandline argument -Dlinux.experimental=true" and when I close the pop-up window, in the editor area it says "Could not open the editor: Invalid thread state detected on read." How do I solve this problem? Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the file and select Open with... then select MyEclipse JSP Editor. If that's not in the list, select Other and then find the MyEclipse JSP Editor and select it. Thereafter, the file will open with that editor and not the Visual Designer, which is only experimental on Linux and not available for many configurations.